# Unable to restore Database, Database is in use by session

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 and I am having an issue restoring my database I receive this message upon trying to restore my database.

> Restore failed.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)
>
> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE cannot process database
>   'AMOD' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that
>   the master database be used when performing this operation.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)"

I have restarted the program I did not open any tables contained within the database and I still receive this message. I am new to SQL Server and this is my first time doing a restore. I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to kick all the users out, and make sure you're not in that database too. Assuming you're in Management Studio, you need to change your context to a different database (or switch the database dropdown to a different database) this way, and this will also kick out any other users (which could be you - Object Explorer, Object Explorer Details, other query windows, etc. could all be inadvertently preventing the restore by maintaining a connection to your database):

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE AMOD SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Once you've finished restoring and the database is ready for use again:

```
ALTER DATABASE AMOD SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: I was setting this up for another user, and I additionally had to go to Security → Logins → right-click user → Properties and set the Default database to master, then have them log out and back in.

Comment: @bmaupin kicking them out temporarily should have solved that, too.

Comment: I guess what I meant was I was setting up another user to be able to restore the database, but every time they would log in to do the restore, the database they wanted to restore was set as the default so they'd connect to it. Granted, I'm no expert, but changing the default DB seemed to fix it. At any rate, great answer!

Comment: @bmaupin ah I see, yes, if they were the user doing the restore, but then again they could always issue `use some_other_database;` before attempting the restore.

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity manager to kill resource dependencies in a script or else kill SPID as simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to master to restore a current database as shown below:

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Connection string for the SQL Server database
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=YourServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"

        ' Path to the backup file
        Dim backupFilePath As String = "C:\Path\To\BackupFile.bak"

        ' Name of the database to be restored
        Dim databaseName As String = "YourDatabaseName"

        ' SQL query to switch to the master database
        Dim switchToMasterQuery As String = "USE master"

        ' SQL query to restore the database
        Dim restoreQuery As String = $"RESTORE DATABASE [{databaseName}] FROM DISK = '{backupFilePath}' WITH REPLACE"

        ' Create a SqlConnection object
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            ' Open the connection
            connection.Open()

            ' Create a SqlCommand object to switch to the master database
            Using switchToMasterCommand As New SqlCommand(switchToMasterQuery, connection)
                ' Execute the switch to master query
                switchToMasterCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

                ' Create a SqlCommand object with the restore query and connection
                Using command As New SqlCommand(restoreQuery, connection)
                    ' Execute the restore query
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Console.WriteLine("Database restore completed successfully.")
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```