# Create a database from a .bak file in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a test database from the production database, but I keep getting the following error:

> Restore of database 'TestLeo' failed.
> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

Here are the options I used.

[image]

I'm not sure if something is missing. I've tried everything and can't seem to achieve it.

I was hoping to create a test database using a `.bak` from the production database.

Comment: Are you trying to restore into an existing database?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I know, but as you yourself have written in the answer below, it seems, the target for that operation is (probably erroneously) set to an existing database. Because if you select a `.bak` file, SSMS typically suggests the original name of that file as target.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to restore from a backup to a database that already exists and is in use.
If you want to replace that database you'll need to drop it, or prevent users (including you!) connecting to it to allow the restore process to get an exclusive lock. This will cause the existing database to be overwritten, so be sure that's what you want to do.
If you don't want to replace it, choose a new name for your copy. You can do this from the general tab of the GUI (Destination-> Database).

Comment: @AaronBertrand From that point of view, yes, my comment may be worded ambigously, but I actually meant the same as you in your answer ...

Comment: If you are deadset on using the UI for this the problem is because the original was in full recovery mode and the tail-log backup option is checked. If you first uncheck that it should work. I just helped one of our devs with this exact issue a couple of weeks ago. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I really, really, really wouldn't point and click through the UI to do this. It will lead you astray in about 15 different ways.

You want to create a *copy* of the database that's there. That means you need to give it a different name (since database names are unique) and move the files to a different location (since you can't overwrite the files for the existing database). So the first step is to run the following query in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @bak varchar(1024) = CONCAT
(
  'C:\DB\Testing\Backup\Production_Test',
  '\Production_Test_backup_2023_10_06_014001_8731590.bak'
);

RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @bak;
```

This will tell you the files you need to move. Let's say the logical names are `Leo` and `Leo_log`.

(This assumes the original source database was named `Leo`; it's unclear if the error message is because you tried to use the original name or if you've tried to restore the test database more than once.)

Next you need to figure out where to put them. One way is to check where the source database's files are stored:

```
EXEC Leo.sys.sp_helpfile;
```

This will provide you paths in the `filename` column where the original database's data and log files are stored, maybe `D:\data\Leo.mdf` or `C:\Program Files\...obnoxious path...\Leo.mdf`. There may be more than two files, they may be spread in different locations. You want to replace `Leo` in those paths with `Leo_copy` or something similar.

You indicated in a comment you want the files to be in `C:\DB\Testing\Data`, so, fair enough. Leaving the above in as it may be helpful to future readers who don't know the paths ahead of time.

Now write a `RESTORE` statement like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Leo_copy
  FROM DISK = 'C:\...that path...\...that file....bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE 'Leo'     TO 'C:\DB\Testing\Data\Leo_copy.mdf',
  MOVE 'Leo_log' TO 'C:\DB\Testing\Data\Leo_copy.ldf';
```

If you can't do that because `Leo_copy` already exists and is in use (which is why your previous attempt failed), see:

- [Unable to restore Database, Database is in use by session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982185/61305)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try to execute this query you mentioned. I have a folder where the .bak files are stored from the production database. Here is the path:
C:\DB\Testing\Backup\Production_Test
There is a .bak file named: Production_Test_backup_2023_10_06_014001_8731590.bak
Please ignore the "Test" as these names were left as they are, but this is the production database and its backups.
After this .bak, I want to create a new database located in C:\DB\Testing\Data named TestLeo.

Comment: I've already checked, and there is no database with that name. It would be the only one. Do you think I can run your script with this data?

Thank you.

Comment: @LeonelRivera Updated but again I can't see your system so I don't know if you can run the code as is. You will have to check the logical file names from `RESTORE FILELISTONLY`, for example, and validate they are correct in the code. You will also need to make sure the backup file contains exactly one backup - with the timestamps you should be safe, but a common problem is people make multiple backups to the same file, and if they don't use `FILE =`, it takes the _oldest_ file.